# Why am I getting a linker error: undefined reference to ...?

Tags: c++, g++, ld

Why am I getting this error: `` undefined reference to `bfopen(char const*, int)' ``?

I have a shared library that I created that includes a function definition for the function `bfopen` among others. The name of this library is `libfiles.so` and it is in a local `ext/lib` directory to where I am building from.

and I am compiling with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -fPIC -g -Wall -D_DEBUG -I$(PWD)/src -I$(PWD)/ext/include -o parser_tst parser_tst.cc $(PWD)/src/parser.o -L$(PWD)/ext/lib -lpthread -lfftw3f -ldsp -lfiles
```

I've substituted `$(PWD)` for my working dir. I've looked inside `libfiles.so`  with `nm -D ext/lib/libfiles.so` and was able to find the function definition listed there so I am at a loss. I also don't get any errors like `file does not exist: libfiles.so` so it seems like it is at least linking with that file.

Here is a sample of my setup: (all paths are clipped to their local path)

ext/sample/src/test.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

int test();

#endif /* TEST_H */
```

ext/sample/src/test.c:

```
#include "test.h"

int test() {
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the cleaned file structure:

```
.
./ext
./ext/Makefile
./ext/sample
./ext/sample/src
./ext/sample/src/Makefile
./ext/sample/src/test.c
./ext/sample/src/test.h
./ext/sample/tst
./ext/sample/tst/Makefile
./ext/sample/Makefile
./ext/sample/ext
./src
./tst
./tst/test_tst.cc
./tst/Makefile
./Makefile
```

after calling `make build` it looks like this:

```
.
./ext
./ext/Makefile
./ext/sample
./ext/sample/src
./ext/sample/src/Makefile
./ext/sample/src/test.c
./ext/sample/src/test.h
./ext/sample/src/test.o
./ext/sample/tst
./ext/sample/tst/Makefile
./ext/sample/Makefile
./ext/sample/ext
./ext/sample/include
./ext/sample/include/test.h
./ext/sample/lib
./ext/sample/lib/libtest.so
./ext/lib
./ext/lib/libtest.so
./ext/include
./ext/include/test.h
./src
./tst
./tst/test_tst.cc
./tst/Makefile
./Makefile
```

and finally I call `make test` which produces the output (including the error):

```
make  -i -C ./tst
make[1]: Entering directory `$(PWD)/tst'
make all_tst
make[2]: Entering directory `$(PWD)/tst'
g++ -std=c++11 -fPIC -g -Wall -D_DEBUG -I./src -I$(PWD)/ext/include -o test_tst test_tst.cc -L$(PWD)/ext/lib -ltest
test_tst.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test_tst.cc:4:6: warning: unused variable ‘t’ [-Wunused-variable]
  int t = test();
      ^
/tmp/ccMq869q.o: In function `main':
$(PWD)/tst/test_tst.cc:4: undefined reference to `test()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: [test_tst] Error 1 (ignored)
make[2]: Leaving directory `$(PWD)/tst'
make[1]: Leaving directory `$(PWD)/tst'
```

I tried using the tcsh equivalent of `export` (`setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH .`) and that didn't help

Comment: Please add a code example that reproduces this error.

Comment: my codebase is quite large. I will try produce an example with the same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible problem is, that you have `ext/sample/src/test.c` a C-file, which will compiled as C-code.

But your application which uses your library is C++ code

```
g++ -std=c++11 -fPIC -g -Wall -D_DEBUG -I./src -I$(PWD)/ext/include -o test_tst test_tst.cc -L$(PWD)/ext/lib -ltest
```

and includes a header, which is in this case also compiled as C++-code from the c++ file but compiled as C-code from your C-file!

So you should include your header from the c++ code with:

```
extern "C" {
#include "test.h"
}
```

How to mix C and C++ code: [mix C and C++ code](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp)

The reason why the linker will not find the symbol from the c-file is, that names are "demangled" in C++, because it needs a "trick" to do the function overloading. A better and more detailed explanation can be found here: [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Standardised_name_mangling_in_C++)